# С++, числовой ребус. если АБ * ВГ = ДДД и Д * ВГ - АБ = ВВ, то чему равно АБ * Г?

Tags: c++, массивы, логика, перебор

необходимо составить алгоритм решения данного ребуса на **C++**. каждой букве соответствует цифра от 1 до 9. должен выполняться линейный перебор чисел, их разложение в массив цифр.

```
int ab, vg, ddd, vv;  
for (int a = 1; a < 10; a++)   
  for (int b = 1; b < 10; b++)  ... // перебор таким же образом оставшихся букв  
    int ab = a*10 + b; 
    int vg = v*10 + g; 
    int ddd = d*100 + d*10 + d; 
    vv = v*10 + v;  
    if (ab * vg == ddd && d * vg == vv + ab) std::cout << ab * g;  
  }
```

вариант с 5 вложенными циклами не устраивает тем, что крайне неэффективно, хочу узнать более креативные способы решения.

задача состоит не просто в решении ребуса, нужно написать программу, читайте пожалуйста вопрос внимательнее

Comment: очевидно, что БД. Или нет?

Comment: а че интересного? ответ итак ясен 37*12=444  и  4*12-37=11

Comment: Программу нужно? Ок: `cout << 74;` Если хотите чтобы было «поинтереснее», решайте эту задачу в общем виде, для любых утверждений на входе.

Comment: Я думаю Вы ошиблись место, здесь не решают задачи за Вас. Собственно в чем возникла у Вас сложность в решении задачи. Приведите свои варианты, и напишите чем они не устраивают Вас

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin сделал через перебор каждой цифры отдельным циклом
`int ab, vg, ddd, vv;

for (int a = 1; a < 10; a++) {

for (int b = 1; b < 10; b++) { ... // перебор таким же образом оставшихся букв

int ab = a*10 + b; int vg = v*10 + g; int ddd = d*100 + d*10 + d; vv = v*10 + v;

if (ab * vg == ddd && d * vg == vv + ab) std::cout << ab * g;

}}`
не устраивает тем, что крайне неэффективно, хочу узнать более креативные способы решения

Comment: @vp_arth, а разве не `O(n^5)`? 5 же переменных и все нужно перебрать друг с другом?

Comment: @detdoomed, перенеси код из комментария и пояснение что в нем не устраивает в сам вопрос.

Comment: Любая оптимизация, отход от полного перебора включает в себя анализ задачи. А раз мы начинаем анализ задачи, что заставит нас остановиться на полпути и не решить её полностью? Именно поэтому `cout << 74;` вполне корректное решение.

Comment: @Grundy, удалил коммент про O(n). Нет, не O(n^5), скорее O(9^n), но не нужно забывать, что у нас n<=9 =)

Comment: @vp_arth, например, наличие нескольких решений? :-)

Comment: @vp_arth, а, да :-) перепутал количество итераций в цикле с количеством циклов :)

Comment: @detdoomed, за разными буквами могут быть одинаковые цифры?

Comment: *вариант с 5 вложенными циклами не устраивает* не 5, а 4. Ибо Д однозначно определяется значениями Б и Г.

Comment: Ну сразу же видно по форме ДДД, что в числа АБ и ВГ входят множители 3 и 37, и минимально возможный дополнительный множитель уже приводит к указанному ответу.

Comment: Выстраиваем буквы - АБВГД. Проверяем, что их не 10 :) Выбираем все *размещения* по 5 цифр из 9, сопоставляем каждое букве, вычисляем выражения. Все. Самый общий случай... Я когда-то такую написал один раз, и хватит :), но не поделюсь - она разгребает и корни, и факториалы, использует YACC, многопоточная - словом, для вас она не пойдет. Но в общем случае решение именно такое.

Answer (score 1):

Накидал, авось зайдёт за «более креативное решение» :-)

- Циклы заменены генерацией размещений
  *реализовано как «все перестановки для каждого сочетания»*
- Итерируются только 3 переменные, остальные 2 вычисляются
- Алгоритм проверки решения вынесен в отдельную лямбда-функцию

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

// #define CALC

/**
 * Mutate «current» into next combination
 * Returns false if provided current state is a last combination
 */
template <int N, int K>
bool next_combination(std::array<int, K> &current, int min = 1) {
  auto head = current.begin();
  auto tail = current.end();

  auto max = min + N - 1;

  // current combination is last: {max-K+1, max-K, ..., max-1, max}
  if ((*head) == max - K + 1) return false;

  auto it = tail;
  while(*(--it) == max - (tail-it) + 1);
  (*it)++;
  while (++it != tail) *it = *(it-1) + 1;

  return true;
}


/**
 * Traverses all (9, N) permutations and prints all solution, if found
 */
template <int N>
void solve(int (*get_solution)(const std::array<int, N>), int no_solution)
{
  std::array<int, N> digits;
  // Set initial combination: 1, 2, 3, ..., N
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) digits[i] = i + 1;
  do {
    std::array<int, N> vars(digits);
    do {
      int solution = get_solution(vars);
      if (solution != no_solution) {
        std::cout << solution << "\n";
      }
    } while (std::next_permutation(vars.begin(), vars.end()));
  } while(next_combination<9, N>(digits));
}

int main()
{
#ifdef CALC
  const int no_solution = -1;
  solve<3>([](const std::array<int, 3> args) -> int {
    int a = args[0];
    int b = args[1];
    int g = args[2];

    int d = (b * g) % 10;
    if (d == a || d == b || d == g) return no_solution;

    int v = (10 + d*g - b) % 10;
    if (v == a || v == b || v == g || v == d) return no_solution;

    int ab  =  10 * a + b;
    int vg  =  10 * v + g;
    int ddd = 111 * d;
    int vv  =  11 * v;

    return (ab * vg == ddd) && (d * vg - ab == vv) ? ab*g : no_solution;
  }, no_solution);
#else
  std::cout << "74\n";
#endif
}
```